# new to lists on python

Tags: python, arrays, list, input, numbers

This is my current code:

```
while True:
        try:
            mylist = [0] * 7
            for x in range(7):
                    sales = float(input("Sales for day:"))
                    mylist[x] = sales
                    if  sales < 0:
                        print ("Sorry,invalid. Try again.")
        except:
            print ("Sorry, invalid. Try again.")
        else:
            break

print (mylist)

best = max(sales)
worst = min(sales)

print ("Your best day had", best, "in sales.")
print ("Your worst day had", worst, "in sales.")
```

When I run it I get this:

```
Sales for day:-5
Sorry,invalid. Try again.
Sales for day:-6
Sorry,invalid. Try again.
Sales for day:-7
Sorry,invalid. Try again.
Sales for day:-8
Sorry,invalid. Try again.
Sales for day:-9
Sorry,invalid. Try again.
Sales for day:-2
Sorry,invalid. Try again.
Sales for day:-5
Sorry,invalid. Try again.
[-5.0, -6.0, -7.0, -8.0, -9.0, -2.0, -5.0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Si Hong/Desktop/HuangSiHong_assign9_part.py", line 45, in <module>
    best = max(sales)
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

I am not quite sure how to code it so that, the lists do NOT take in negative values, because I only want values 0 or greater.

I am not sure how to solve the TypeError issue so that the min and max values will print as in my code

My last issue is, if I want to find the average value of the seven inputs that an user puts in, how should I go about this in pulling the values out of the lists

Thank you so much

Comment: sales is a float ... `max(my_list)` ... is what you want ..

Comment: The average is just `sum(my_list)/len(my_list)`

Comment: (assuming by average you mean the arithmetic mean)

Comment: Actually in Python 2.x you need `float(sum(my_list))/len(my_list)` -- otherwise, if all the values are integers, it rounds the average to an integer

Comment: @stuart , thanks i got this to work now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to put the data checking into a while loop. This will keep looping over this value until your conditions are met (`>0`)

Also, this could get confusing for the user to figure out what day they are entering the results for. Plus you need to be using the list for the max/min, not individual values. Put it all together, and make the following changes:

```
        for x in range(7):
            sales=-1
            while (sales<0):
                sales = float(input("Sales for day {0}".format(x)))
                mylist[x] = sales
                if  sales < 0:
                    print ("Sorry,invalid. Try again.")
```

And later make this change:

```
best = max(my_list)
worst = min(my_list)
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to put in the day to the input-text as well (e.g. `'Sales for day {0}'.format(x+1)`)

Comment: thanks for the help, but i was wondering what I can do in case the user enters something like "one hundred" instead of 100, @pearsonartphoto

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-in-python

Answer (score 3):

Did you mean to say:

```
best = max(my_list)
worst = min(my_list)
```

As to the validity check, the problem there is that if the input is invalid, you still move on to the next value of `x`.

Answer (score -1):

maybe (untested):

```
mylist = []
while len(mylist) < 7:
    sales = float(input("Sales for day %s:" % str(len(mylist)+1)))
    if  sales >= 0:
        mylist.append(sales)
    else:
        print ("Sorry,invalid. Try again.")

print (mylist)

best = max(mylist)
worst = min(mylist)

print ("Your best day had", best, "in sales.")
print ("Your worst day had", worst, "in sales.")
```